# why does my toilet have two overflow tubes and a refill line that tees?

Tags: toilet

I bought a house that has a second bathroom in the basement. I would like to replace this toilet.

It appears to have a single water inlet and two over flow tubes. The refill hose tees into the regular overflow tube and into a second overflow tube. The second tube has a line out of the toilet tank and into the wall.

The tank model is a Proflo 3112 - E. I have not found any information online that refers to this setup.

What kind of toilet is this and where does the second overflow tube go?

[image]

Comment: Looks like whatever it is was retrofitted to one of the tank bolt holes.  This is interesting.  Any chance of a photo under the tank on that right side?

Comment: The view doesn't reveal much - the line exits the tank and into the wall. Nothing more.

Comment: So on the _right_ side there is a line that exits the tank and goes into the wall?  I know the water supply line on the left probably does that.  On the right, under the tank, you should see where the metal tube that your tee-d filling line goes into exits the tank.

Comment: yes, the second overflow line exits the tank and goes into the wall. It's a braided line, looks similar to a supply line, but no valve.

Comment: Where are you located in the world?  I've never seen that - I hope someone else can share some knowledge.

Comment: And that tee'd fill hose just sits in that second overflow tube. Not a lot of pressure. I believe, because of the restriction device inline.

Comment: USA, Oregon, high desert climate.

Comment: Is it going to a trap that might run dry if not primed?

Comment: I've seen a bathroom where this additional line runs water into a basin for hand-cleaning once you're done with the toilet; the outlet runs water while the toilet fills so you can (quickly) clean your hands. But, here the line isn't pressurized, so the basin would have to be on the floor. Is there something else that would need a dose of water every flush?

Answer (score 4):

It's a line to fill other traps that may run dry when not used. Every time you flush some water is diverted to top up the traps and prevent a sudden stink of sewage.

These traps that need topping up would be for example the floordrain in the basement or the drain for a water heater safety valve.